# theano less than function gives wrong answer

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, theano.scan

Here is a code snippet :

```
seqLen = 4
seq = np.repeat([seqLen-1],seqLen)
print seq

def step2(idx):
    if T.lt(idx,seqLen-1):
        return T.constant(True)
    else:
        return T.constant(False)
    # return T.lt(idx,seqLen-1)

    final,updates = theano.scan(step2,sequences=[T.arange(0,4)]
                             ,outputs_info=None)

    iter = theano.function([], outputs=[final],updates=updates)
    result = iter()
    print 'result', result
```

The output that I am getting is -

```
result [array([1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int8)]
```

Shouldn't the output be array([1, 1, 1, 0]). Am not able to understand how the sequence 'idx' is being passed to the step function.
Shouldn't it send each value of `T.arange(0,4)` at each time step and then `T.lt(idx,3)` should return false just for the last time step and true otherwise.

Update: if I modify the step2 function as -

```
def step2(idx):
    return T.lt(idx,seqLen-1)
```

then I get the correct output as [1,1,1,0]. I need to use the conditional statement as a if condition only. Any help?

Update 2: Instead of using pythonic 'if' construct, I tried theano's 'ifelse' and it worked. But I want to execute a bunch of statements based on the condition and that is why 'ifelse' is not feasible.

Thanks

Comment: if your question is how can you build theano graphs using pythonic if-else constructs the answer is probably that you cannot. The possibility of using regular binary operators like `+` and `*` between theano ops is possibly because python allows to overload such binary operators, but I don't think such a thing is possible for ternary operators such as if-else constructs. See also [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35859464/4063051)